# Is this possible to find a good binary image by otsu method for such image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Is this possible to find a good binary image by otsu method?

Binarization of such image using otsu method doesn't show good output for any threshold value I tried for this image:

[image: a6.jpg]

<sup>*a6.jpg*</sup>

Here is my code:

```
A=imread('a6.jpg');
im=rgb2gray(A);
figure,imshow(im); title('gray image');
im=A(:,:,1);
[q r]=size(im);
s=r/2;
if true
    %code
    n1 = im(:, 1 : end/2); %image(x,y,c) c is matrix displayed as image
    n2 = im(:, end/2+1 : end );%indicate last array index
    if true
        D=imhist(n2)-imhist(n1);
        thresh_level = graythresh(D);  %find best threshold level
        c=zeros(size(im));
        [r c1] = size(im);
        allpix=im;
        allpix(allpix>thresh_level*200)=1;
        allpix(allpix<=thresh_level*0)=0;
        c=allpix;
        figure,imshow(c); title('binary image');

    end
end
```

Is there any threshold value for which I can get a good binary image?

Comment: So you claim that your program implements Otsu's method?

Comment: Certainly the output image `c` is not a binary image. Also there seems to be a *lot* of unnecessary code, please keep your example minimal.

Comment: I couldn't understand Why it's not a binary image and the implementation isn't the otsu method.if u explain,it will be helpful for me.

Comment: So if the snippet is not the otsu method, *why* did you include it in your question then? Regarding the bineary: Just try `hist(c(:))` and you will see that it is not binary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your program is doing but this should be sufficient:

```
A=imread('a6.jpg');
im=rgb2gray(A);
imshow(im); title('gray image');
c=im2bw(im,graythresh(im));
imshow(c); title('binary image');
```

And it outputs

[image]

Comment: That image is no good for text recognition. Though it's far from catastrophic as a binarisation. The stroke width transform uses Canny edge detection instead.However the blurry area will be challenging whatever you do.

Comment: You're right, however OP did not mention anything about text recognition, he was asking about Otsu's method in MATLAB: